# how to make googlevis plots fit the screen automatically in R

Tags: r, plot, size, screen, googlevis

I am trying to make a chart in R via `googleVis`.
How do you make the chart automatically fit the size of the screen, or rather, the browser?

```
library('googleVis')
Column <- gvisColumnChart(df,
                          options=list(legend='none'))
plot(Column)
cat(createGoogleGadget(Column), file="columnchart.xml")
```

Comment: Please see the answer below and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear from documentation, who seems to want you to use pixels, say `width = 200` in pixels, *but* you can use the word **"automatic"** which scales nicely.

So snippet from one of my functions:

```
 # where plotdt has my data with columns px and py
 plot1 <- gvisBarChart(plotdt, 
                       xvar = px,
                       yvar = c(py),
                       options = list(width = "automatic",
                                      height = "automatic")
```

Note in your case, add to your option list

```
gvisColumnChart(df,
                options=list(legend='none',
                             width = "automatic",
                             height = "automatic"))
```

Hope this helps others.

Plus, useful link for more on [configuration options](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options). *This is for bar charts, so choose the right chart/table type for you on left of page.*

**TEST IT**

Since there is no data above in `df` for those who want to play with this:

```
library('googleVis')

# some test data, add your own
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), 
                 y = c(2,4,6))

plotdata <- gvisColumnChart(df,
                            options=list(legend='none',
                                         width = "automatic",
                                         height = "automatic"))

plot(plotdata)
```

Comment: Thanks @micstr, +1 for answering it. I tried your code and it does fit the width of the browser for the initial plot. But then when I change the browser, the plot does not adjust its size automatically.

Comment: Frankly, the question was asked about 2 years ago, and I did not write it clearly whether I wanted it to be resizing interactively or I wanted it to fit the screen at the initial plot, so I do not recall which of the above two issues I was trying to solve. But I did try my code again and it appears that without adding "automatic", the initial plot still automatically fits to the screen. Therefore, I assume adding "automatic" did not help. (It could be that googleVis changed their default setting over the past year and half such that it fits the screen by default now).